# Random walk on a connected graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-walk

I am reading a book and I have a problem understanding why a relation holds.
Assume that we have a time-homogeneous
random walk on a connected graph $G=(V,E)$.

For $o\in V$, the roundtrip from $o$ is the random walk from o that stops
upon the first return to $o$. Let $j_o(e)$ be the expected number of times that $e\in E$ is traversed in a roundtrip from o. Let also $\pi(x)$ be the expected number of visits to $x\in V$ in a roundtrip from o. Then,

$$j_o(x\to y)=\pi(x) p(x\to y).$$

Why does this hold? Maybe I have to use the law of total expectation in a way that I don't see.

Comment: The only way we can traverse the edge $xy$ from $x$ to $y$ is to first get to $x$ and then go to $y$, so if we expect to get to $x$ $\pi(x)$ times, and we have the probably $p(x\to y)$ of going along the edge $xy$, we expect to traverse the edge $\pi(x)p(x\to y)$ times.

Comment: @SeanEnglish that's what the relation tells us but what you wrote is not a proof.

Comment: You are right it is not a proof(note it being a comment), but do you understand it? If you get the idea, you should have no problem showing the result rigorously.

Comment: Does this not help? I can go into more detail if necessary, but I'm not sure what part you are stuck on.

Comment: @SeanEnglish I have a problem showing it rigorously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional probability.

For any positive integer $i$, and let $A_i$ be the random variable that takes the value of $1$ if and only if the $i$-th edge traversed in the roundtrip from $o$, if any, is $(x \to y)$. Then clearly $j_o(x \to y) = E[\sum_{1 \le i} A_i] = \sum_{1 \le i} E[A_i]$ (by linearity of expectation).

Similarly, let $B_i$ be the random variable that takes the value of $1$ if and only if the $i$-th node traversed in the roundtrip from $o$, if any, is node $x$. Then we have $\pi(x) = E[\sum_{1 \le i} B_i] = \sum_{1 \le i} E[B_i]$.

By definition, $p(x \to y) = \Pr(A_i | B_i=1) = E[A_i | B_i=1]$. Combining all these:

\begin{eqnarray}
j_o(x \to y)
&=&\sum_{1 \le i} E[A_i]\\
&=&\sum_{1 \le i} \left( E[A_i | B_i=1] \Pr(B_i = 1) \right) \\
&=&\sum_{1 \le i} \left( p(x \to y) E[B_i] \right) \\
&=&p(x \to y) \sum_{1 \le i} E[B_i]\\
&=&p(x \to y) \pi(x)
\end{eqnarray}